# Android Studio stuck when creating new Flutter project

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I have installed Flutter on Windows and checked all is ok using flutter doctor.
I imported the Flutter plugin.

Now, when I try to create a new Flutter app via Anroid Studio it never ends.
I get "Creating Flutter Project" and that's it.

The message area contains ""C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\flutter.bat" --no-color create --template app --description "A new Flutter application." --org anykey.co.il flutter_app4"
It seems to be stuck on "Building symbols...".

I even left it on overnight hoping it would finish.

In the end I have to kill it.

Edit:
It seems that my flutter.bat file is looping.
I tried flutter doctor (who echo set to on) and this is what I get.
The last part loops forever.

```
C:\Users\user>flutter doctor

C:\Users\user>REM Copyright 2017 The Chromium Authors. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\user>REM Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be

C:\Users\user>REM found in the LICENSE file.

C:\Users\user>REM ---------------------------------- NOTE ----------------------------------

C:\Users\user>REM

C:\Users\user>REM Please keep the logic in this file consistent with the logic in the

C:\Users\user>REM `flutter` script in the same directory to ensure that Flutter continues to

C:\Users\user>REM work across all platforms!

C:\Users\user>REM

C:\Users\user>REM --------------------------------------------------------------------------

C:\Users\user>SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

C:\Users\user>FOR %i IN ("C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\..") DO SET FLUTTER_ROOT=%~fi

C:\Users\user>SET FLUTTER_ROOT=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter

C:\Users\user>SET flutter_tools_dir=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools

C:\Users\user>SET cache_dir=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache

C:\Users\user>SET snapshot_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\flutter_tools.snapshot

C:\Users\user>SET stamp_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\flutter_tools.stamp

C:\Users\user>SET script_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\bin\flutter_tools.dart

C:\Users\user>SET dart_sdk_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk

C:\Users\user>SET engine_stamp=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\engine-dart-sdk.stamp

C:\Users\user>SET engine_version_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\internal\engine.version

C:\Users\user>SET pub_cache_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\.pub-cache

C:\Users\user>SET dart=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\dart.exe

C:\Users\user>SET pub=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\dart-sdk\bin\pub.bat

C:\Users\user>REM If available, add location of bundled mingit to PATH

C:\Users\user>SET mingit_path=C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\mingit\cmd

C:\Users\user>IF EXIST "C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\mingit\cmd" SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools;C:\Program Files\Calibre2\;C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin\;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;c:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY;C:\Program Files (x86)\GtkSharp\2.12\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\rexx.org\Regina;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\user\AppData\Roaming\Dashlane\4.6.8.26847\bin\Firefox_Extension\{442718d9-475e-452a-b3e1-fb1ee16b8e9f}\components;C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin;;C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\mingit\cmd

C:\Users\user>REM Test if Git is available on the Host

C:\Users\user>where /q git   || ECHO Error: Unable to find git in your PATH.   && EXIT /B 1

C:\Users\user>REM  Test if the flutter directory is a git clone, otherwise git rev-parse HEAD would fail

C:\Users\user>IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\.git" (
ECHO Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
 EXIT /B 1
)

C:\Users\user>REM Ensure that bin/cache exists.

C:\Users\user>IF NOT EXIST "C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache" MKDIR "C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache"

C:\Users\user>REM To debug the tool, you can uncomment the following lines to enable checked mode and set an observatory port:

C:\Users\user>REM SET FLUTTER_TOOL_ARGS="--checked "

C:\Users\user>REM SET FLUTTER_TOOL_ARGS=" --observe=65432"

C:\Users\user>(
REM "3" is now stderr because of "2>NUL".
 CALL :subroutine doctor   2>&3 9>"C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\flutter.bat.lock"  || GOTO acquire_lock
) 2>NUL

C:\Users\user>(
REM "3" is now stderr because of "2>NUL".
 CALL :subroutine doctor   2>&3 9>"C:\Program Files\Flutter\flutter\bin\cache\flutter.bat.lock"  || GOTO acquire_lock
) 2>NUL
```

---

Second edit:

Output of "flutter doctor -v"

```
    [v] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.1.5, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.248], locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 0.1.5 at C:\Program Files\flutter
    • Framework revision 3ea4d06340 (13 days ago), 2018-02-22 11:12:39 -0800
    • Engine revision ead227f118
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.28.0.flutter-0b4f01f759

[v] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 26.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-26, build-tools 26.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[v] Android Studio (version 3.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-915-b01)

[v] Connected devices (1 available)
    • Nexus 10 • R32F201H9ME • android-arm • Android 5.1.1 (API 22)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: Does ’flutter create flutter_app4` in a shell work?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Trying it now. How long should it take? If less than a minute then it is not working. :(

Comment: Ok, so it's not related to the IDE, but only to your Flutter setup. What output does `flutter doctor -v` produce?

Comment: So, now flutter doctor is not finishing either. It seems to be in some sort of a loop. I added "echo on" to see. The output is in my update above.

Comment: I'm not able to make sense from this output. I'd try reinstalling Flutter (no a sophisticated answer, I know)

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yeah. Seems the best idea. Will have to wait til tomorrow.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Still no good. Managed to get "doctor -v" to work.

Comment: Are you behind a firewall?

Comment: @theblitz Your project location path folder name is valid Dart package name.

Answer (score 14):

Had the same issue.

Just run Android Studio/IntelliJ in administrator mode. It works.

Comment: it works perfectly but may I know what are the possible reasons. Its not good running android studio each time as administrator

Comment: @muhammadobaid Sorry for the really late reply. I haven't been using flutter for a while. Regarding your question, I believe it was because flutter was installed into a restricted storage space (I guess its the C drive here)

Answer (score 7):

For windows 10 there is couple of solution here, I am sharing with here which is working for me.

**1.** Set Flutter SDK path is present in AS Settings . `Settings > Languages & Settings > Flutter > Flutter SDK Path`

**2.** Run Android Studio/IntelliJ in **administrator mode**

**3.** Your project location path folder name is **valid Dart package name**.

Comment: Right! As usual It's clear, if the Flutter SDK  is located in C:\, Android Studio cannot run flutter, because it requires administrator's grants. So, open it with them and create your project.

Answer (score 5):

This is likely because you've put Flutter in `Program Files` which requires admin permissions to be able to write its cache files.

I've got a [PR Open](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/17975) that should result in a more friendly error, but I'd recommend moving Flutter away to a folder that non-Admin users can write to.

Answer (score 3):

In my case this was the issue - I checked create project offline checkbox. Please sure that this checkbox is unchecked.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

After selecting options and when "**creating new Flutter project**" appeared, end Android Studio process and re-run it then - *instead of creating a project*- choose **Open Project** and select the project folder that you created before .

Comment: This trick worked Man. @nAviD thank you so much.

Answer (score 1):

I was struck with the same problem a while back. After a lot of stumbling I got it right.
First of all delete your previous cloned flutter files and install git in your user folder. Like
`C:\users\username\`

Clone flutter in your git directory,set the path 
`C:\users\username\git\flutter\bin`

Now use the command flutter doctor 
If you have android studio and intellij IDE, install flutter plugins in both of them and now create a new project.

You are all set to go

Answer (score 1):

For me this worked in Windows 10 :

- Flutter SDK location : kept it under c:\Users<username>\AppData\Local
- Project location : kept it under c:\Users<username>\AppData\Local
- Start Android Studio in Administrator mode : **this was not required** it worked without Administrator privilege
- While creating the new Flutter project : **create project offline** choose this option (another answer in this same post which has a screenshot says, do not select it, but for me it worked only after selecting this option)

How much time it took to create the project ? **2 minutes**

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue on windows 10 . Make sure  path of the Flutter SDK is present in AS Settings . Settings > Languages & Settings > Flutter > Flutter SDK Path

Answer (score 0):

I have **disabled the Antivirus(Quick Heal)**, and run the CMD as administrator and run "**flutter**" command. It's working. Then checked the "**flutter doctor**" command, It's also working fine.

Then started the AS as administrator mode and create the flutter app and it's started working now.

Answer (score 0):

in windows try to run android studio as administrator and create new flutter project

Answer (score 0):

It might sometimes be as a result of the current version of Flutter and Dart plugins. Check the plugins and update if requested. **File >> Settings >> Plugins**

Answer (score 0):

I also get this same issue. close the android studio from task manager and run cmd as administrator. now type

taskkill /F /IM dart.exe

and press enter.
Now run your ide and create a flutter project. I solved this problem in this way

Answer (score 0):

The solution which worked for me in windows.

I have placed flutter sdk folder in **C:\Program Files**.

When android studio try to access the folder, it wont work as **admin rights** is required for that folder.

1. Run android studio as administrator and create a new project
2. Else flutter sdk can be placed in User folder
   **C:\users\username\flutter** or other drives which does not require
   elevated rights.