# While creating flutter project I am unable to start my project

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, flutter-test

My flutter sdk is in c drive and not in program files. Tho my android studio is in program files.

When running flutter doctor it is not showing no error. Just when running my first flutter application it's just showing the message new project to be created but there is no output.
Please help[the display message output is shown in the picture:

[image]

Comment: Try running Android Studio as administrator. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138139/android-studio-stuck-when-creating-new-flutter-project and https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/16659

Comment: Already tried running Android Studio as administrator but it still didn't work. Also tried most of the solutions given in those thread but all proved unsuccessful in my case