# I have an issue with configuring Flutter in console

Tags: android-studio, flutter

I wanted to install flutter use Android studio to develop the app. But when i run flutter doctor in console, i get this  error:

```
[!] Android Studio
X Flutter plugin not installed; this adds Flutter specific functionality.
X Dart plugin not installed; this adds Dart specific functionality.
X android-studio-dir = C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\bin
X Unable to find bundled Java version.
```

Comment: It might be a possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51281702/unable-to-find-bundled-java-version-on-flutter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Android Studio stuck when creating new Flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49138139/android-studio-stuck-when-creating-new-flutter-project)